# Clarifying some notation, the square of a vector derivative

Tags: vectors, notation

I'm reading a text which asserts that, if $\vec{F}(\vec{x})=-\nabla V(\vec{x})$ then we define
$$E = \frac{m}{2} \left( \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}\right)^2-V(\vec{x}) \, .$$
However, I don't understand how you can square $d\vec{x}/dt$ since this is a vector function.  Does this mean that the vector is dotted with itself?  Or are we not taking the coordinate-wise derivative of $\vec{x}$?

Comment: "Does this mean that the vector is dotted with itself?" Yes.

Comment: @lemon that should be an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kinetic energy of a particle whose motion is described by $\textbf{r}(t) = \left(x(t),\,y(t),\, z(t)\right)$ is, at the point $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, defined as
$$
T(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 + \dot{z}^2\right) =
\frac{1}{2}m\,\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{v}
$$
and yes, the square of a vector means (by abuse of notation) its scalar product with itself.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an abuse of notation. You can assert that the square of a vector is the vector dotted with itself and from that fact and associativity and distributivity and such you can generate a whole algebra in which the vectors live with their friendly neighborhood bivectors and trivectors and such inside an algebra that is as simple to use as a matrix algebra. And those algebras do come up anyway, such as the Pauli Algebra or the Dirac Algebra.

Comment: @Timaeus It's an abuse of notation because it's not standard and probably not defined in the book or OP wouldn't have had to ask.

Comment: @DanielSank You can call it advanced rather than abuse

Comment: I can hardly put to words how much the idea of calling undefined notation "advanced" distresses me. That notion is antithetical to efficient communication, which is what books are presumably for. Woe to any student subjected to a teacher with that attitude.

Comment: @Timaeus I expect the product of two elements of an algebra to be in the same algebra (by definition), and in this sense the scalar product of a vector with itself is not (it is a scalar, instead). Then if we convey on new universal definitions well yes, we can re-dine everything from scratch, although I cannot see why this would be useful.

Comment: Advanced means that it is a standard use that more advanced students will encounter. It is horrifying when a book uses advanced notation that the students are not yet exposed to and haven't seen properly defined yet. Using the word advanced makes it clear what the exact issue is, the book uses notation that they and others understand perfectly and that you will see later, but that was not introduced to the students. It clearly identified the exact error. Calling it an abuse makes it sound like it isn't something that be very single advanced student knows

Comment: @GennaroTedesco You can expect anything you want. However, nature demands we use the Pauli and Dirac Algebras because no one knows a way around using them. And it is normal for multiplication to make different things, consider any number with units, then multiplying them makes them something different, e.g. a density times a volume gives something that is neither a volume nor a density. And when you multiply a vector times another vector you might get a squared length and you might get an area element but you always get something with units equal to the product of the units of the vectors.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco And you can always make an algebra of multivectors. Have scalars be multivectors, have vectors be multivectors, have bivectors and trivectors be multivectors. Then you get the product of two multivectors is a another multivector. If you don't know why it is useful it is something that advanced students have to learn anyway, that also works for the note elementary studies in physics and is a proper subject. Planes exist, and it is an accident of 3d that planes are simple and have as many linearly independent basis elements as vectors.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Students then have to relearn the basics of how to use vectors when they get to quantum and relativity. They have to relearn vector calculus too because we teach a hack for 3d that doesn't generalize. And using geometric algebra right from the beginning means there is much less unlearning, more generalization, wider applicability, more unification, and if done right doesn't have to make the simple things any harder. Its more like just admitting that you can span subspaces with vectors and just talk about them geometrically as well as algebraically, rather than hacking 3d.

Comment: @Timaeus I don't see how any of the above comments is relevant to the question asked. Since this is a physics Q&A platform users ask questions and they reply according to the mathematics and the physics we currently have knowledge of. Then if you want to re-formulate the teaching I agree and go ahead, but that is not relevant argument for an answer. And by the way, the Pauli and Dirac algebras do not satisfy what you have mentioned, rather their representations on the same space do (which is a different thing).

Comment: @GennaroTedesco My comment is on this particular answer, I don't think the notation is an abuse, I think it is wrong to use advanced notation that hasn't yet been introduced properly. And you can make an algebra without making a representation of it. For instance you can make a Clifford algebra out of any quadratic form, and leave the representations to people that feel like making them.